# How To Show Progress Bar On a WebView In MonoDroid

Tags: c#, webview, progress-bar, xamarin.android

I have been trying to display the progress bar implementation in a `WebView` used by an app using monodroid. I have reached quite far but couldn't seem to solve the last part of the puzzle. I am using the paid version of Monodroid Pro and am using Galaxy S2 as the test device.

Here is what I have done so far :-

In the `OnCreate` Section :-

```
        Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.Progress);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Window.SetFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.Progress, Window.ProgressVisibilityOn);

        wv.SetWebViewClient(new monitor());

        wv.LoadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Now on the onprogress changed override method :-

```
  private class progress : WebChromeClient
  {
        public override void OnProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
        {                    
           base.OnProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
  }
```

Now the solutions I have seen are for java implementation of Android which is quite easy, i.e :-

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
    {
        //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
        MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
        MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

        //Return the app name after finish loading
        if(progress == 100)
            MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
     }
 });
```

But using monodroid i can't use `SetProgress` method as in the Android implementation, the `Activity` instance can be made in `OnCreate` Method, whereas in Monodroid a whole new class is to be made and then `webchromeclient` is to be inherited first and then so on. What am i missing? Is there another way that I don't know about? Some help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't support anonymous classes like Java, as you noticed, so you need to define a separate class. The [`Activity.SetProgress()`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Activity.SetProgress) method is public, which means that you can pass a reference to your activity into the class, and use that to call the method:

```
public class CustomWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    private Activity _context;

    public CustomWebChromeClient(Activity context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override void OnProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
    {
        base.OnProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

        _context.SetProgress(newProgress * 100);
    }
}
```

Then your activity could create an instance of this class, passing itself into the constructor:

```
webview.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this));
```

I have a more complete browser demo [available here](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/tree/master/MonoDroid/BrowserDemo) that may also help you get going.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your detailed help man!, this was really helpful!. Your given link to the guide will also prove very helpful . After this I will be concentrating on intents, i.e receiving link from browser, sending to another activity etc. Already have the intent-filter thing done, handling part remains.  Again, thanx very much !